# How to count group records based on certain values?

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

I have a report, divided into set of groups, one of them is grouped by "Status".
Status values are: S, R, V.

I need to make two total fields to get
1- Count of S and V records.
2- Count of R records.

Any suggestions?

FYI: I use CrystalReport Designer embedded with VisualStudio.NET 2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do it by using running totals.Put a formula which only select the appropriate records into the running total's evaluate option. You will have two running total -one for the S and V records and another one for the R records.